Netlogo: efficient iteration using 'foreach'
I want to calculate and store two certain quantities associated with turtles' properties, namely count how many turtles meet a condition and the sum of these turtles' specific attribute. That specific attribute takes discrete, integer, non-sequential values.
A minimal example code of the model would look like this:
globals [ N-x1 N-x2, N-x5 sum-A-x1 sum-A-x2 sum-A-x5 x-list ]

turtles-own [ condition1? A x ]

set x-list ( list 1 2 5 )

Given that in the actual model the x-list takes 88 discrete values I thought using a 'foreach' loop would be an appropriate way to handle this. Note that the number of turtles in the actual model is around 75k so efficiency matters.
Following a combination from previous answers (here and here), I came up with the following solution:
  foreach x-list
  [ x ->
    
    ; Count turtles by x
    let temp1 (word "set N-x" x " count turtles with [ condition1? = true and x = " x "]" )
    run temp1
    
    ; Calculate sum of A by x
    let temp2 (word "set sum-A-x" x " sum [ A ] of turtles with [ condition1? = true and x = " x "]" ) 
   
   ; Capture errors due to empty list in calculating the sum
    carefully [ run temp2 ] 
    [ let temp3 (word "set sum-A-x" x " 0" )
      run temp3
    ]
  ]

Although it works, each run of the model was substantially slowed down. A simple (yet crude) solution that I thought it would help to speed up the code is to first define the turtle agentset on which the subsequent commands (counting and summation) will be performed. Since I could not find a way to use let inside the 'foreach' loop to do that, I went with the manual solution of defining everything by hand (for every single of the 88 values of x):
; Define needed agentsets
let turtles-x1 with [ condition1? = true and x = 1 ]
let turtles-x2 with [ condition1? = true and x = 2 ]
let turtles-x5 with [ condition1? = true and x = 5 ]

; Count turtles meeting condition1
set N-x1 count turtles-x1
set N-x2 count turtles-x2
set N-x5 count turtles-x5

; Sum A over turtles meeting condition1
if N-x1 > 0 [ set sum-A-x1 sum [ A ] of turtles-x1 ]
if N-x2 > 0 [ set sum-A-x2 sum [ A ] of turtles-x2 ]
if N-x5 > 0 [ set sum-A-x5 sum [ A ] of turtles-x5 ]

That seemed to improve performance by a small margin. Could anyone think of a more efficient (i.e. smarter) way to do the same? E.g. using map, which I can't my head around of, or the table extension?
Edit: While answers are still welcome, I've found a way to solve the issue using table extension and map. I'm leaving it here in case someone stumbles upon a similar case.

I'm glad you found a solution that works for you!  It's okay to leave an answer to your own question on SO, and is encouraged.  You should mark it as accepted as well, so anyone else who finds it will know it solved this problem.

Thanks @Jasper , done! (And apologies for the ignorance about the community's rules/norms.. :-) )

Following the answers found here and here the -much more efficient- solution is:
globals [ x-keys x-N turtle-list turtle-A ]

; Store table of relevant turtles and their x's (to preserve order)
let temp-table table:group-agents turtles with [ condition1? = true ] [ x ] 

; Relevant turtles' Xs (in the order inserted)
set x-keys table:keys temp-table
  
; Counts of relevant turtles per x (in the order inserted)
set x-N map count table:values temp-table
  
; Relevant turtles in the order inserted (in an agentset list)
set turtle-list table:values temp-table

; Calculate sum of A per x
set turtle-A map [ y -> precision ( sum [ A ] of y ) 3 ] turtle-list

This solves many issues such as predefining every variable, executing multiple if's to check whether an x is populated or not (i.e. N > 0) for the sum to run and storing unneeded information (e.g. manually setting the sum of cases with N = 0, to zero). This greatly improved speed and halved the size of generated output (in a BehaviorSpace experiment).
